# GMM with Bayes decision model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normal-distribution, matlab, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Given two classes of training data (A and B),  I want to fit each class' distribution using a GMM with k components, and then use Bayes Decision Model for the classification.

The first step was to use PCA on data set A, project the data into 
a lower-dimensional subspace, and then for each class do the actually fitting.

In MATLAB this would be implemented as:

```
>> Aobj = gmdistribution.fit(A, k, 'Regularize', 1e-5);
>> Bobj = gmdistribution.fit(B, k, 'Regularize', 1e-5);
```

However, when I evaluate the pdf for the the training data:

```
>> pdf(Aobj, A)
```

one or two of the data points are assigned huge values (3.200989873206918e+241).

What am I missing here?

Data set: collection of 50x25 grey-scale images with A and B indicating the presence or absence of pedestrians.

Comment: Have a look at the variance of each component. My guess is that one component is just covering one point and thus has very low variance (and very high density).

Answer (score 1):

When you get a result like that it means you have a component assigned to a single point.  It is using a Gaussian to approximate a dirac-delta function whose center is at the point.  Reduce the number of components by the number of "crazy" values and try again.

It is not a bad idea to run the fit a few times (10-30) and then pick out the median fit, or the most "well behaved" fit.